# Word usage, colloquy

Tags: word-usage

How do I use the word "colloquy"?

I don't understand how it is used. I know the meaning is "A conversation".

My context: "My friends and I are having a colloquy about politics."

"My family are having a colloquy about the case." etc..

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've found so far.

Comment: What does that mean? Sorry I am new

Comment: No problem :) . The community is usually quite happy to help, but prefers questions to come with some context, together with what is loosely called *research*. That is, what have you found about how *colloquy* is used, and what puzzles you about such usage, etc?

Comment: It's also annoying when someone posts an answer, only to get a reply along the lines of, "Oh, I already knew that. I was hoping for more information." Showing your work helps avoid such situations.

Comment: Okay done! Added some context.

Comment: Your examples are fine. But note that this word sounds a bit pretentious. Many dictionaries mark it as a "formal" word. It's not at all common where I'm from.

Comment: Have a look at [this help page](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [these posts](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=colloquy). This site is intended to be a repository of expert answers, and it may be the case that an answer already exists somewhere on the site. If those posts don't help with your question, link to relevant ones in your question and add a note to say what other information you're after.

Comment: Dictionary entries (e.g. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/colloquy)) also often provide usage examples. I hope this all helps with your research and to gain some familiarity with this site. :)

Comment: I struggle to find a context where I would use this word over the word **conversation**. Maybe if I were in a room with Teddy Roosevelt, Winston Churchill and Oscar Wilde ;P But then again I would probably use the words "parley" or "confabulate" in that context. So nope, I'd never use the word 'colloquy'

Comment: Wordnik can be a good source to see how words are actually used: https://www.wordnik.com/words/colloquy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Colloquy* meaning *conversation* is a literary word, meaning it's used in literature. It is not part of most people's everyday vocabulary. By most people, I mean 99% of native speakers (of American English, at least). So the answer is we almost never use the word in spoken contexts.

An exception is  the second definition found at [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/colloquy), *a gathering for discussion of theological questions* and that involves about  .0005% of the population.

In short, you can stick this word in your passive vocabulary in case you run across it in print; if you're anything like a typical native speaker, you will not have to actually say it, ever.